# Cant connect to AWS EC2 instance after start/stop IP Reassigning

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, http

My EC2 instance kept going offline. Ihave httpd service start on it. Apparently there was no way to solve the issue. I had a hack that I tried to connect via in-browser (using Mozilla, Chrome has deprecated) and then after some time it just worked automatically. However, eventually I was forced to stop/start thus leading to change of my dynamic ip allocated to me (Yes, I am using free non-static ip version!)

So, currently, I am not able to ping or connect via http at this new instance even though I have made sure my permissions are set correct.

P.S. : Following is the wget output when tried to do on self via terminal:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-47 ~]$ wget ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
--2017-07-03 06:28:01--  http://ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
Resolving ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com)... 172.31.11.47
Connecting to ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-13-126-184-237.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com)|172.31.11.47|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.fitolicious.com/ [following]
--2017-07-03 06:28:03--  http://www.fitolicious.com/
Resolving www.fitolicious.com (www.fitolicious.com)... 35.154.222.25
Connecting to www.fitolicious.com (www.fitolicious.com)|35.154.222.25|:80
```

And then it just hangs to eventually give Connection Time Out.

Answer (score 1):

So your original IP on the instance was 35.154.222.25 and then it was restarted and got a new IP 13.126.184.237? And when you connect to the new IP you get HTTP redirect to http://www.fitolicious.com/ which is resolved back to the original IP 35.154.222.25? Do I understand that right?

If that's the case you must update the IP of www.fitolicious.com to the new one 13.126.184.237.

And I would also allocate "Elastic IP" to the EC2 instance instead of using the standard Public IP. Elastic IP stays with the instance even if it stops and restarts, unlike the standard Public IP that changes every time the instance stops. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html
Don't worry, Elastic IPs when assigned to instances do not cost anything.

Comment: You might want to explain more clearly what you mean by *"you must update the IP."*  What this means is perhaps only obvious to someone who already knows that the problem is in DNS configuration, and not (e.g.) configuration of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Also, note that Elastic IP Addresses are only free when attached to a **running** instance, and only one EIP per instance is provided at no cost. It's possible to attach more than one, and they are billable after the first one.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - thanks for the suggestion, apparently the OP understood my advice as the DNS is now updated :)

Comment: @user1599964 - if the advice has helped please accept the answer as correct to award for the time and effort spent helping you, thanks! :)